# Run CSS file through Twig when using {% stylesheets %} tag in Twig with Symfony2

Tags: css, symfony, twig, assetic

I'm including CSS stylesheets in my template like so:

```
{% stylesheets
    "@SomeBundle/Resources/assets/css/default.css.twig"
    "@SomeBundle/Resources/assets/css/global.css.twig"
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

However I want to run these CSS files through Twig, is this in any way possible while using the `{% stylesheets %}` tag or does this require some other approach. I've already tried enabling a `twig` filter but that does not exist.

Comment: The `stylesheets` tag is no related to Twig. This tag is contributed by `AsseticBundle`. Could you clarify your question, I have hard time understanting what you try to achieve :)

Comment: @Matt Well I want to keep the benefits that Assetic gives me, while running the stylesheet through Twig first.

Comment: @Xeross if you could say more specifically _why_ you want to do this, you may see better results.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it if you load the css as an internal stylesheet. Something like this:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% include 'AcmeBundle:Bundle:mycss.css.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

And then the mycss.css.twig template would contain:

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* */
</style>
```

Comment: Yes this did come to mind, however you lose the benefit of having your styles in a separately cached file.

Answer (score 1):

Most common things you'd want to do by processing CSS with Twig should be possible with [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or similar, which can be applied as Assetic filters. First tutorial Google threw up was this one: http://alexandre-salome.fr/blog/Sass-Compass-Assetic-In-Ten-Minutes

Admittedly, that doesn't look like much help if you're unable to run Ruby/Node.js/whatever on the production server you're developing for, but it should be possible to create an Assetic filter based on one of the PHP ports of Sass/LESS (assuming they're any good) if that's the case.