# Rendering a CSS file using Twig

Tags: php, html, css, twig, template-engine

I'm using Twig as a Template Engine.
I want to render my CSS files though Twig, with the advantage of macros.
The response I receive looks fine. But somehow if I include it, the HTML page doesn't recognise it as a css file.
When I include the real css files, the site works just fine.
The comparison of the received source code is exactly the same...

Although, Chrome displays the files differently. 
It displays the rendered file on one line.
It is probably being interpreted as a HTML file.

The real css file is being displayed like the source code, on multiple lines.

You include both files with the extension of .css.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you get the correct contents, but it's not interpreted as css. This could be because of an incorrect contenty-type header.

Css files should be sent as `text/css`, in Sf the default is `text/html`. In the action that renders your css make sure to set the correct header.

Comment: Yes, that sounds legit. Do you know how to do this in Twig? Google didn't know the answer.

Comment: Ok, it worked by setting header("Content-Type: text/css"); Isn't there a more elegant way?

Comment: You can set headers in your controller on the `Response` object.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should take a look at [LESS](http://www.lesscss.de/) its more effizient instead of parsing your CSS files. With LESS you have a lot of possibilities to make blocks and reuse functions with variables.

Perhaps its an alternative for your problem.

**Edit:**
[Template Suffix](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#template-suffix)
[Run CSS file through Twig when using {% stylesheets %} tag in Twig with Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033172/run-css-file-through-twig-when-using-stylesheets-tag-in-twig-with-symfony2)

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to keep that plan B. I'm already using Twig for all of my files, that's why I wanted to do the same with my CSS files.

Comment: I have added 2 links with solutions.

Comment: The engine suffix didn't solve my problem. I think Twig isn't type-specified. The second link hasn't a solution yet.

Comment: Take a look at the solution. Thanks for your help though.